# Open file in default application in iOS app running on Apple Silicon M1 Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am working currently on adapting our Email application written on Xamarin iOS to run correctly on Apple Silicon M1. I have faced the following problem that I can't solve so far. The problem is that our code written for iOS that uses `UIDocumentInteractionController` on Apple Silicon opens "Share to" menu, also if I try to change this to `Launcher.OpenAsync()` call from Xamarin.Essentials it also opens "Share to" menu instead of opening the file with default application. I tried to use `Launcher.OpenAsync()` from Xamarin.Mac application and run it directly on Apple Silicon from VS Mac and it works as expected this way - opens file with default application. However when running from iOS application installed on Apple Silicon it always opens "share to" menu. It is a big problem for us as we need to allow user to open attachments files from our email editor. Any ideas what I can try to do to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi, do you mean it only occurs *when running from iOS application installed on Apple Silicon*, how about other Macs whithour M1?

Comment: Hi, we don't have Mac application, only iOs Application, and as M1 supports running iOS apps we want to use this possibility as our users want to use our application also on Macs. So the problem happens when we run this code from iOS app on M1.If I create Xamarin.Mac application directly in Visual `Studio Mac installed on M1 and run the code Launcher.OpenAsync works as expected and opens the file with default application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I replaced our `UIDocumentInteractionController` with [Quick Look Preview Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/QuickLook.QLPreviewController?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) which works as expected both on iPhone and iOS application running on M1.